# How to execute Umbraco v4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, umbraco4

i was given a project wherein i will be sustaining an old Umbraco v4 project that has a remote database server. how will i be able to understand the architecture with such obsolete technology.

Comment: It depends entirely on the build, but assuming it's a standard .NET 2 build in WebForms it's probably maintainable. Either way, depending on the size of the build and the amount of content in the CMS I would definitely pitch for a port to Umbraco 7/8.

Comment: yes i get what youre saying. there is a new project that is currently in staging. but for now we still have to sustain the current umbraco 4 project

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: take your time. You'll get it in time. There's also a lot of old parts of the documentation still lying around on the internet.

The mentality behind it is still the same. You'll just find weirder ways of the previous developers doing things and that will take you more time to get how it works.

You could also look at obsolete editors on the documentation.